# Basic Bluetooth example causing problems

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently trying to further my knowledge in using Bluetooth in Android studio, but for some reason I cannot seem to get the App I am working on to acknowlege or request permissions for Bluetooth. I cant help but think theres something I am missing, but from what I have seen in other forums, Bluetooth works out of the box.

What I would like to happen is when the app opens to add Bluetooth devices found into a listbox at the bottom of the screen

The App compiles ok, gives me a message to tell me Bluetooth is on or off but then when accessing Bluetooth feature just crashes out. For purposes of Brevity I have omitted the permissions in this code sample.
I have refined the issue to

```
  val pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter!!.bondedDevices
```

But cannot understand what I am doing wrong, can someone help please?
Here is My Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.adamvi">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AdamVI"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.Toast
import java.util.Arrays


class MainActivity : Activity() {

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
        val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = bluetoothManager.adapter

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Bluetooth is switched on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()

                val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
                val listView = ArrayList<String>()
                val pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter!!.bondedDevices
                pairedDevices.forEach { device ->
                    listView.add(device.name.toString())
                }
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Bluetooth is switched off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Bluetooth permissions are so called [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime). You need to request access at runtime as well as declare the usage in your manifest. According to [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions) for targeting Android 12 and above:

> The BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, and BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions are runtime permissions. Therefore, you must explicitly request user approval in your app before you can look for Bluetooth devices, make a device discoverable to other devices, or communicate with already-paired Bluetooth devices.

and for targeting Android 11 and below:

> Because location permissions are runtime permissions, you must request these permissions at runtime along with declaring them in your manifest.